# client side changed disabled state, but not reflecting at server side after postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

ASP.NET 4

I have a server control DIV.
at client side, it will be programmatically disabled. verified at client side the property disabled is true

after postback caused by submit button, this DIV disabled is false at server side.

why is the disabled state not reflecting at server side?
the control EnableViewState is by default true

Answer (score 1):

Any DOM manipulations done on client side will not reflect on the server as the view state is not aware of this manipulation.

To get a better understanding of EnableViewstate, please follow this link [What does EnableViewState on a HyperLink do or mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417985/what-does-enableviewstate-on-a-hyperlink-do-or-mean).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `disabled="disabled"` not `disabled="true"`?

Because if you render disable attribute via code-behind you will have

```
<div ... disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: the manipulation is only happened at client side.
server side I don't need to change it, but I want to check it's state on postback.